Передать переменную в pyTelegramBotAPI
Требуется передать переменную start в функции register_callback_query_handler
Вот мой код:
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

start = "start"


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(call):
    menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="кнопка", callback_data ='calculator'))

    msg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text="text", reply_markup=menu)


bot.register_callback_query_handler(calculator, func=lambda call: call.data == 'calculator', pass_bot=True, start=start)


def calculator(call, bot, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. Никаких ошибок не вылетает.
Тем не менее, если не передавать именованных параметров в функцию register_callback_query_handler, то функция calculator нормально вызывается.
Ума не приложу, в чем проблема.
